# Image src not get right pat in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I tried to display an image in view page, but the `src` attribute is incorrect.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\new\public\uplode/Screenshot_5.png

but src is:

> http://localhost/new/C:\xampp\htdocs\new\public\uplode/Screenshot_5.png

```
function is:`public function bpl(){
    $ob=banner::all();
    return view('admin.page.bpl',['var'=>$ob]);
}
```

View file is:`<img src="{{asset($ob->bannerimage)}}">`.

How do I get the right path in view file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your view file.Use this link i belive it will resolve your issue.

```
<img src="{{asset('uplode/Screenshot_5.png')}}"/>
```

Comment: brother i try this @foreach($var as $ob) <img src="{{asset($ob->bannerimage)}}">@endforeach

Comment: Can you provide me your database table screeshot?

Comment: yes brother screenshort link is [link](https://i.imgur.com/AL2prQw.png)

Comment: all table in the database screenshort link [link](https://i.imgur.com/bM7wd7M.png)

Comment: Structure screenshort is [link](https://i.imgur.com/AL2prQw.png)

Comment: please your submit form screenshot?

Comment: submit form screenshort link [link](https://i.imgur.com/OGm1OnI.png)

Comment: try getClientOriginalExtension you are using getClientOriginalName

Comment: I believe you any minor mistake on your code.Debug on the imageuploadcode method and after insert database check the file name and also check the image  is saving on destination folder or not.And use getClientOriginalExtension for image extension read.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
 $filename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
 $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

you should save only the file name and extension like (filename.png) on database. you have save desktop actual path which contains /\ both so image destination is not working properly.